# Finding correct flyback transformer for ZVS mode

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I'm trying to design an offline flyback smps based on a [L6565](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/58/8c/b2/de/5d/05/49/c2/CD00004217.pdf/files/CD00004217.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00004217.pdf) chip from ST with 5V@1A output. I've found a small transformer from [Coilcraft](http://www.coilcraft.com/pdfs/lph8045-223.pdf) with auxiliary winding and turn ratio 1:1:1.

If I understand everything correctly, it can't work in ZVS mode, cause turns ratio 1:1 won't produce reflected voltage higher than input voltage, but I can use it in quasi resonant mode?

Comment: What is your end goal? Why not wind your own transformer?

Comment: My end goal? I need a very small power supply for my MCU circuit. I don't need much power but its limited to small available space. 
I don't have experience in winding transformers, coils etc., and measuring transformer's parameters could be a problem for me. So such transformer, LPH8045 isn't right choice for L6565?

Comment: Why do you need it to work in zvs mode. Sounds like an xy problem to me.

Comment: I don't need it to work in ZVS, I just want to do something pro :P
In fact, working in ZVS will decrease losses and temperature will be lower. In my MCU circuit I am using temperature sensor.

Comment: Ok guys, so if I give up the idea with ZVS, this transformator is right for such application?

Comment: You need to define input voltage range, output voltage level and current range of load to be able to choose a flyback transformer. Also, operating frequency might be significant to you so you need to specify that also.

Comment: Input is 88-264Vac, output 5V, 50mA - 1A. However I have no idea how to choose switching frequency. Do you have any guide for newbies?

Comment: Pro = know how to choose and calculate your transformer parameters and wind it. Also, pro =! easy off-the-shelf transformer solution. You are in a clear X-Y pitfall, just like Andy says.

Comment: So what should I do? Any source for good starting point?

Comment: @winny You're right, that's pro :)
Maybe I should find another controller IC for high-speed switching, where transformer can be relative small?

Comment: Is it not possible to get an off-the-shelf supply from somewhere? I mean, the iphone charging cube is something like 25mm on a side and some of the Sony bricks are even smaller (albeit with lower power ratings 1.5A vs 2.1A). How small are we talking here? If you need something smaller than a 25mm cube, it's one heck of an involved process to build a 5W mains power brick in that small of a space (I've seen 14W in that size but that had a whole design *team* associated with it). My advice would be to find an existing power cube and shoe-horn it into whatever it is that you're building.